# (ADAL) integration with Ionic 3 getting “We are unable to issue tokens”

Tags: azure, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, azure-ad-msal

I’m using MS ADAL for login authentication in ionic 3.
Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ms-adal/

Login screen appearing , when i'm login, its sending issue,
getting error :

"AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this."

code:

```
authContext.acquireTokenAsync(‘https://graph.windows.net’, ‘4324dsad-b5c3’, ‘http://localhost:8000’,"","")
.then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
console.log(‘Token is’ , authResponse.accessToken);
console.log(‘Token will expire on’, authResponse.expiresOn);
})
.catch((e: any) => console.log(‘Authentication failed’, e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, you may login with a personal Microsoft account. But [Azure AD authentication library (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) uses `v1.0` endpoint, it does not allow personal Microsoft account to sign in, the v1.0 endpoint allows only **work and school accounts** to sign in to your application.

See this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#who-can-sign-in

[image]

Comment: then how can i change it to v2.0 ? is there any setting available ?

Comment: @GaneshGodshelwar If you want to use v2.0, you need to use a [v2.0 AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) and [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries), not ADAL. But why don't you use a work/school account to sign in? Just new a user in the Azure Active Directory in the portal, then you will get a work account.